# unable to make scaled heatmap for diffrential gene analysis

Tags: r, heatmap, bioinformatics, bioconductor, pheatmap

Im new to R so be easy on me, I'm having trouble generating a heatmap for my genes. I performed diffrential gene analysis using DESeq2 package and found the 30 most downregulated genes and with fdr<0.05 for cell lines. I was trying to create a heatmap using the pheatmap package and I wasn't able to generate my heatmap as I want to. I want to generate a heatmap for my top 30 genes for each cell line(which are 8)
Here's my code :

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = GSM_subset,
                          colData = subset,
                          design = ~ Condition)

d_analysis <- DESeq(dds)
res <- results(d_analysis)
res

nrow(dds)
dds <- dds[rowSums(counts(dds)) > 1,]
nrow(dds)        


mcols(res, use.names = TRUE)
summary(res)

resLFC1 <- results(d_analysis, lfcThreshold=3)

table(resLFC1$padj<0.05)
resLFC1 <- resLFC1[complete.cases(resLFC1),]
resLFC1
resSig <- subset(resLFC1, log2FoldChange=-3)
resSig <- subset(resLFC1, padj<0.05)
top30=head(resSig[ order(resSig$log2FoldChange), ],30)
top30<-as.data.frame(top30)

library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(top30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Heatmaps in the genomics context usually use the scaled (that is Z-transformed) normalized counts on the log2 scale, or similar transformation such as `vst` or `rlog` from the `DESeq2` package.

Given you already use DESeq2 you can do with `dds` being your `DESeqDataSet`:

```
vsd <- assay(vst(dds)) # log-normalized and variance-stabilized counts
Z   <- t(scale(t(vsd))) # z-transformation
Z.select <- Z[your.genes.of.interest,] # subset to genes of interest
```

...and from there use the heatmap package of your choice.